# Rewrite Rules different filename same redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

I would like to have something like that in .htaccess:

^Test/filename/param --> mydirectory/test.php?id=$1

The filename can be different each time but the redirection will always be the same. Only the parameter will change.

I would be very grateful if you could help me because I'm very confused.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

use regular expressions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule folder/(.*)$ folder/test.php?id=$1
```

also may be cache problem and try it in incognito mode.